# Какая разница между классами-"пространствами имён" и библиотеками функций?

Tags: классы, php, сравнение, функции

Мне нужно реализовать функции, к примеру, по работе с аккаунтами в проекте.
Сейчас у меня это файл `player_func.php` с набором функций с названиями `player_*` для удобства.
Имеет ли плюсы вот такой вариант:
создание файла с классом `Player`, а в нём все нужные функции как методы.
К примеру, раньше

```
player_register();
```

А теперь:

```
Player::register();
```

*Я обсуждаю не функции VS **объекты**, а функции VS **классы** в качестве "пространств имён".*

Comment: Мне кажется, что вариант с классом лучше. Однотипные функции собраны в одном классе, что немного упрощает понимание работы программы.

Comment: @ReinRaus, ну в случае с функциями понимание улучшали префиксы.

Comment: Скромное ИМХО - если используете функциональный подход и классы если и будут применяться то исключительно для организации кода - лучше использовать пространства имен, либо, как вы уже писали - префиксы.
****
Не много не в тему, но - с применением функционального подхода можно писать на ура, особенно если с умом использовать безымянные функции.

Comment: @AlexWindHope, я пока больше в функциональном стиле (вроде он правильно называется "процедурный"?). А что вы имеете в виду под 

>> безымянные функции

Comment: Функциональный я написал что-бы всем было понятнее, по поводу безымянных функций, приведу простой пример:

     $hello = function() { return 'Hello world'; };
     function execAndEchoClosure( $closure ) {
          echo $closure();
     }
     execAndEchoClosure( $hello );
     // или
     execAndEchoClosure( function(){
         return 'Hello world';   
     })

Ничего толкового код не делает, но если пофантазировать можно придумать этому уйму применений.

PS: работает все это в php v5.3+.

Comment: А, в смысле анонимные функции, которых в jQuery куча?
@AlexWindHope, не могли бы привести пример применения в PHP(в смысле случай)?

Comment: Например у вас есть массив с функциями для валидации, количество функций и то, что они делают - никому не известно. Мы пишем функцию для добавления функции валидатора, функцию для получения результатов в виде (есть ошибка - или нету) и функцию для получения сообщений ошибок (если они есть).

Это к примеру. Так-же, например, вы можете имитировать что-то типа событий и подписчиков без ООП. Вообще для того что-бы очень хорошо понимать как этим пользоваться надо хорошо знать языки аля javascript, lisp etc. Но и так, думаю, полет фантазий я открыл, а если нет - забудьте об этом и не парьтесь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никакой разницы кроме — очевидно — синтаксической. Классы, которые никто *никогда* не инстанциирует в объекты — по сути, просто пространства имен. Префиксы имен функций — по сути, то же самое¹.

В PHP с не особо давнего времени появились полноценные [пространства имен](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.namespaces.rationale.php). Возможно, это то, что Вы ищете?

---

¹) Можно посмотреть дискуссию с Joe Armstrong на тему «[а зачем нам вообще модули](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2011-May/058769.html)» и ее [развитие и обсуждение на Hacker News](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2580383). Там достаточно много интересных мыслей о плюсах и минусах.

Answer (score 1):

Кроме синтаксической, в классах можно задать статичные переменные, которые в последствии можно использовать в качестве настроек к функциям, в отличие от обычных, которым придется также задавать префиксы, чтобы случайно не переопределить, плюс можно использовать любое множество не статичных подфункций. Опять же, можно наследовать другие классы с функциями, пользуясь автолоадом, есть еще преимущества, которые сейчас не вспомнил.

**P.S.** Сам пользуюсь классами.